# Doubt on relativity

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, observers

I have a doubt: if in Classical physics the maximum speed is limited to the speed of light, will simultaneity be relative even in  Classical  Physics?

Also, two observers in separate inertial frames, observe that sticks with same rest length appear to be smaller than their own. Is it a paradox?

Comment: If in classical physics the maximum speed were limited to speed of light, it would be relativity.

Comment: Here is a link to Crash Course Physics episode 42 on Special relativity. This topic is mentioned with great animations. Hopefully it will help you think about the problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AInCqm5nCzw

Comment: I think you want to say non-relativistic or pre-Einstein or Galilean relativistic or some such, not classical physics. Classical usually means non-quantum. Relativity is still classical physics.  Also, if you want to see what happens when you limit speeds to the speed of light, you need to specify how you do that.

Comment: Okay. What I meant is if we take it to be a postulate in non-relativistic physics?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. That's one of the counterintuitive parts of the relativity theory. For our daily life classical physics is a good enough approximation because the effect is very small. I suggest you read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity) Wikipedia article that describes it very well.

Summarized: Because of the relativity of length a moving observer can see things happening simultanously while a stillstanding observer may see them happen separetly.